# gscam core dumped with ximagesrc

Tags: gscam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to use gscam for capturing a window image.
First, I have perfomed a simple test with:

$ export GSCAM_CONFIG="videotestsrc ! video/x-raw-rgb,framerate=5/1 ! ffmpegcolorspace"

And it works nicely. So I have set:

$ export GSCAM_CONFIG="ximagesrc xname=TurtleSim ! video/x-raw-rgb,framerate=5/1 ! ffmpegcolorspace"

But it fails :

[ INFO] [1374835465.214957489]: Publishing stream...
[ INFO] [1374835465.215447284]: Started stream.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

It seems to be the std::copy from the buffer to the image.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/69226/gscam-core-dumped-with-ximagesrc/) by [Enric](https://answers.ros.org/users/3583/enric/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-07-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have figured it out a little bit.

It turns out that gray images do work, with this config:

GSCAM_CONFIG="ximagesrc xname=TurtleSim ! autoconvert ! video/x-raw-gray,framerate=1/1 "

and running gscam in MONO8 mode.

My guess is that the output format from ximagesrc is 32bpp whereas gscam expects 24bpp, so the buffer is overrun.

I haven't been able to make a conversion in the pipeline, but anyway gray images are fine :-)

---

Originally posted by [Enric](https://answers.ros.org/users/3583/enric/) with karma: 16 on 2013-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0